# Objects over curved surface

Tags: mesh

I'm using a template that has a curved mesh (I think), as a background. Like the following image:

[image]

[image]

My problem is that because of the curvature, objects that farther away are cut in half, and I don't want this to happen, shown in the next image:

[image: View from below, objects are not rendered completely]

View from below

I didn't do and do not know how to make that curved mesh, is there a a way that I could make the curvature less soft, or create a new mesh that won't cut the objects?

P.S: I'm a complete noob in blender so please don't get mad if it is supper easy to fix or another reason.

Comment: you could try to select all the surface under your objects and press S Z 0 in order to flatten it

Comment: thanks, i did this and now all the objects are above the plane, but it formed something like a cliff. Nevertheless i'm gonna try it and see how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking [moonbooots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) suggestion

> you could try to select all the surface under your objects and press S Z 0 in order to flatten it

P.S. Don't know how to assign a comment as solution to give him points.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to recreate the mesh:
(in Blender 2.8)

1) Add a cube (*Add->Mesh->Cube*)
Then select and remove all but two sides (*Delete->Faces*).

[image]

2) Bevel the only edge that remained using the *Bevel Tool*.
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>
Set the parameters as desired.

[image]

3) Set smooth shading, so it's perfectly smooth.
[image]

You're done.
You can now position it as you need.

Tip:
If you're a beginner, switch to 2.8. (or 2.81)
It has waaay more friendly user interface and is much easier to work with.

Comment: thanks, i'm gonna try the other suggestion first though, since it was easier to me